# How to send a selected (out of many) input values to DB using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

first post so be gentle :)... OK, I'm trying to create a very simple inventory ordering site, but i'm having issues with the following:

Let's say you have (n) items in your inventory, so based on that number i run a 'for' loop and list a hidden input field with an ID of that inventory item and display a button to order. For example:

```
<form>
for ($i=0; $i<$num_items;$i++)  {
  <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?=$ID[$i]?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Order" onclick="InsertIntoDB()">
}   
</form>
```

Now, lets say a user want to order only 2 item out of 5 in inventory. They would click on corresponding "Order" buttons and the appropriate hidden input values would be send to DB without redirecting (it would be a seamless experience for a user where once the user clicks on buttons they want the page will not reload or redirect). Here's the script that i have for the button click:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function InsertIntoDB (){ 
    var order = $('form input[name="item"]').val();   
    $.post('send_to_DB.php', {updateDB:order} ); }
</script>
```

This is what i have for send_to_DB.php file:

```
|code for connecting to DB|

$writetoDB=$_POST['uptadeDB'];
foreach ($writetoDB as  $n) {
$insert = "UPDATE `test` SET onorder=1 WHERE ID='$n'";
mysql_query(insert);
}
```

I am struggling to get those 2 values that user clicked into the DB. Any help would be much appreciated, lost many hours of sleep due to this one :). Thanks!!!

Comment: the problem is that when you click the order button the selector tag you have written in the Jquerry will select all inputs with the name item. I believe thats the reason you are not getting the value in the PHP file.

Comment: Do you see a coloring problem until the input type submit ? There must be missing something.. seems like PHP code outside of PHP `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: @HarigovindR thanks for the comment... i think you are absolutely correct, but i'm not sure how to fix it. Any thoughts?

Comment: A few typos in the question: `$_POST['uptadeDB'];` should read `$_POST['updatedDB'];` and `mysql_query(insert)` should read `mysql_query($insert)`.

Comment: my simple solution will be to pass the id as an argument for the javascript function so that on click you can access the id from the function itself and pass it to your PHP code

Answer (score 0):

The form will send values for all the inputs in it. One way of overcoming this could be trying to enclose each set of inputs in its own uniquely identified form inside the iteration loop. But consider the following solution which will achieve the required purpose without using a form, and with a single button instead of two inputs for each item:

For the the inputs in the `test.php` file, assuming that array `$ID` is already defined:

```
<?php
$num_items = count($ID);
for ($i=0; $i<$num_items;$i++)  {
?>
<button type="button" value="<?=$ID[$i]?>" onclick="InsertIntoDB(this.value)">Order<?= $i + 1 ?></button>
<?php }   ?>
```

For the posting script in the `test.php` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function InsertIntoDB (order){
 $.post('send_to_DB.php', {updateDB:order} ); 
}
</script>
```

For the handler `send_to_DB.php` file:

```
$writetoDB=$_POST['updateDB'];
$insert = "UPDATE `test` SET onorder=1 WHERE ID='$writetoDB'";
mysql_query($insert);
```

In the above `$insert` query, you might want to use `SET onorder = 1 + onorder` in order to keep track of the number of orders for each item.

However.......: I hope you are aware that we should stop using `mysql_query`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<form>
 for ($i=0; $i<$num_items;$i++)  {
   //<input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?=$ID[$i]?>">
   <input type="submit" value="Order" onclick="InsertIntoDB(<?=$ID[$i]?>)">
 }   
</form>
```

So that in your script you can try this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function InsertIntoDB (order){
    $.post('send_to_DB.php', {updateDB:order} ); 
  }
```

Where order will now have the value id of the selected order